# I'm trying to bulk add a csv file to my local DB

Tags: c#, database, dataset, backend, read.csv

I'm trying to read in the contents of a csv file into my DBcontext object.

Here's the declaration:

```
public DbSet<Wine> Wines { get; set; }
```

All the relevent, configurations were set. But this code just doesn't seem to be working. And I', not getting any errors either.

```
 Wines.AddRange(from wine in File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\cochiagha\\source\\repos\\C_sharp_Projects\\wine.csv")          // Read a row
                        let wineVar = wine.Split(',')
                        select new Wine
                        {
                            Name = wineVar[0],
                            AlcoholContentIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[1]),
                            MalicAcidConentration = float.Parse(wineVar[2]),
                            AshIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[3]),
                            AlcalinityIndexofAsh = float.Parse(wineVar[4]),
                            MagnesiumReading = float.Parse(wineVar[5]),
                            TotalPhenolIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[6]),
                            FlavanoidIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[7]),
                            NonFlavanoidPhenolIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[8]),
                            ProanthocyaninsIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[9]),
                            ColorIntensityIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[10]),
                            HueIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[11]),
                            DilutionIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[12]),
                            ProlineIndex = float.Parse(wineVar[13]),
                        });
```

I instantiated an instance of the db context in my Controller file and called the function under a method I qualified as a 'post'. And my changes were saved after.

```
// bulk read
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public void BulkRead()
        {
            _WineApiDBContext.readCSV();
            _WineApiDBContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If you need more clarification, I'd be glad to provide that too.

Comment: `But this code just doesn't seem to be working` please be more specific,

Comment: Where is `readCSV` coming from

Comment: I mean it’s not adding the contents if my csv file to the database I’m referencing with my dbContext instance

Comment: That’s the name of the function encapsulating the block of code  where ‘Wines.AddRange(…);’ is called.

Comment: Then step-up an appropriate breakpoint, step thru the code looking for where things are not working.